# How to optimize CSS files in C#

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

**I have two css file i.e css1 and css2**

*Both css files contains body tag,i want to combine both body tag into single body tag while loading or bundling*

**CSS1.css**

```css
body {
font-size:larger;
color:darkred;
margin-left: 15px;
}
```

**CSS2.css**

```css
body {
color:red;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

**And, using this bundling configuration:**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssTest").Include("~/Content/Css1.css","~/Content/Css2.css"));
```

**Getting Result**

```css
body {
    font-size:larger;
    color:darkred;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
body {
    color:red;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

**Expected Result**

```css
body {
font-size:larger;
color:red;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you learning a decade old style of development? In modern web development we use C# to create an API and build the front end in a modern framework like Angular, Vue or React. The days of creating ASP.NET bundles have truly been left behind.

Comment: `bundle` meaning: tie or roll up (a number of things) together as though into a parcel.
and this exactly that, it bundles the two files together, you are missing the `minifaction` part.